# Importance of Retorque Lug Nuts

Tags: honda, tires, lug-nut

I just had a new set of tires put into my Honda CRV.  The lug nuts were torqued at 80 ft/lb (manufacturer's specs). The installer told me to come back to retorque the lug nuts after 50 miles.

If the lug nuts were already set at manufacturer's specs, should I even retorque them?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: re-torquing is primarily important with alloy wheels that have flat seat nuts. That is I think extremely rare / non-existant for modern OEM wheels, but if you have aftermarket alloys that may be the case.  Of course it doesn't hurt to check.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just a double check to ensure the wheel hasn't settled onto the rim. If it has, even just a little, lugs can come loose over time. By re-torquing the lugs, you greatly reduce the possibility of it ever happening. If you have a torque wrench and the proper socket, you could do this yourself.

To be honest with you, I don't trust the torque the guys at the shop put on the wheels in the first place. Many are entry level tire changers who have no clue how to correctly operate a torque wrench (if they even use one in the first place). I loosen the lugs and re-torque correctly just to make sure. Most of these guys don't under torque anything, they usually over torque ... by quite a bit.

Comment: it’s funny, you see people gunning on wheel nuts with a 1/2” impact, go around multiple times and then break out the torque wrench.

Comment: Don't most big shops use the impact torque bars now that just snap onto the impact gun?

Comment: @JPhi1618 - They do, but they really aren't that good. They get you in the neighborhood, but don't get it as good as a torque wrench. Even when I've seen guys use a torque wrench, they don't know what they're doing and over tighten the lugs. Next time you get your tires changes, watch what they do and don't focus on "just one guy". Some of them might be doing it right, but I've found it to be hit or miss. I just don't trust them.

Comment: I've seen it too @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, they hit the breakaway point on the wrench and they keep on tightening anyway.

Comment: it is possible to use an impact wrench to spin nuts on without tightening them much. Of course when you go back with the torque wrench they must turn some before reaching the correct torque, else you have no way to know if they are correct vs over torqued.

Comment: @agentp - Absolutely.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thank you for responding! How can I tell "the wheel hasn't settled onto the rim?" What torque wrench and socket do you recommend? Appreciate it.  A total auto noob here. :[

Comment: @Dombey - Well, if you were here in the States, you could get a very cheap, yet reliable torque wrench from [Harbor Freight](https://www.harborfreight.com/1-2-half-inch-drive-click-type-torque-wrench-239.html). Don't know if they have anything like that "North of Norway". You'd need a torque wrench which can achieve at least 80 lb-ft of torque, which is probably a 1/2" drive. Then you'd need a socket which will fit the lugs. You'd also probably need a 5" extension. To make this easy, just find a friend who has the tools you could borrow and show you how to use them.